# MinGW gcc gives errors when other compilers do not

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw

Before you asked, yes i did look this up FOR DAYS.  Im completely stuck...  I'm using MINGW32 (my shortcut says MSYS) to compile my c and cpp code.  For about 2 or 3 days now I have been getting strange errors.  (below)  It was working JUST FINE before.  I even ran the same code i've compiled before and it gave the same error.  I then go into DevC++ and open then compile an it works just fine.

ERRORS:

> namespace: command not found
>
> using: command not found
>
> syntax error:
>       int main(){
>
> (sometimes it gives me a big unreadable mess)

I'm really stuck...   I dont want to have to switch to DevC++...  I like to use my own text editor and compile in a command line.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time posting on anything like this.  I've read a lot of stuff here that helped me so I decided to ask...

Comment: post the "big unreadable mess" please. as well as your actual program.   Not sure how we'd help you without seeing the program.

Comment: I bet you're running gcc instead of g++. Also, this question has nothing to do with IDEs so your point about DevC++ is meaningless.

Comment: Post the simplest possible complete program that causes the errors

Comment: The "command not found" errors indicate that you're actually trying to run your C++ program as a shell script.  If that's not what's happening (or if this doesn't help you figure out what's going on) reduce the code you're compiling to a small program that still shows the same errors, post that code **along with the exact command you use to compile it** and the exact error messages (use copy/paste).

Comment: "my shortcut says MSYS". Well that's not the compiler. That's a *nix-like command interpreter, a.k.a. shell.

Comment: Voted to close as typo, because invoking the wrong program to compile is roughly in that direction. Note: You can test out the compiler in the Windows command interpreter. I prefer to compile small programs that way.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf to be pedantic, `bash` is the shell, and MSYS is a distribution that includes binaries of bash and other common utilities

Comment: @M.M. It's possible that you're right about the name of the final shell executable. As I understand it the OP's `MSYS` shortcut invokes a file called `msys.bat`, which is created by the MSYS installer, and which is a Windows batch file script. This then in turn invokes some executable, probably `bash.exe`.

Comment: @Alf I use MSYS to invoke gcc which is the compiler.

Answer (score -1):

From your errors `namespace: command not found` and `using: command not found` says to me that you aren't compiling the code with an appropriate compiler.

For reference in MinGW32 toolchain:

```
gcc.exe = C

g++.exe = C++
```

You may find it useful to take a look at what the IDE's actualy do with your compiler.
My current IDE allows me to see all the commands that it runs to build my project:

```
C:/mingw32/bin/g++.exe  -c  "C:/MyProgram/main.cpp" -g -O0 -std=c++14 -Wall  -o ./Obj/main.cpp.o -I. -IDependencies/Something/include
```

So lets examine what this does.

My current toolchain is MinGW32 which is located in `C:/mingw32/bin/g++.exe`

g++ is our c++ compiler so we call g++.exe and we pass the following switch:

```
-c "C:/MyProgramm/main.cpp"
```

This tells my compiler to compile the main.cpp from my project directory. then my IDE adds a few additional command line switches. For the purpose of the answer I will only consider `-o`. This tells us the output file from our code main.cpp into an output file.

The reason we produce such a file is to save us time compiling so that we do not have to compile the same file twice without making changes to it. We perform this step on each of our files creating a collection of `.o` files.

The new file is then saved in `"C:/MyProgramm/Obj/main.cpp.o"`

Which means that your command line function will look something like this:

```
C:/mingw32/bin/g++.exe -c "<my project directory>/<file>.cpp" -o ./Obj/<file>.cpp.o
```

I would recommend that you read up on documentation for the g++ function and learn from different IDE's as you will soon find that you need to do more advanced things with your compiler.

For example to enable features from c++14 I add `-std=c++14`

*Edited to reflect feedback.

Comment: I don't know of *any* C compiler that produces "command not found" errors, because C doesn't have commands. So I doubt that the problem comes from feeding the program to a C compiler.

Comment: @rici: C does have commands, or did as of C89, but for some weird reason that terminology is  not used. C stems from BCPL, where commands were called commands also in the syntax. A command is simply a statement that is not a declaration. As I recall in C89 one significant difference was that in a block, declarations had to come before the commands. In C++ any order of statements and commands is permitted in a block, but a C++ translation unit is a sequence of declarations only: no commands permitted in that sequence (i.e. you can't have a command at namespace scope).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: The only usage of the word "command" I can find in C99 or C11 is in section 7.22.4.8, which describes the `system()` function. (...the `system` function passes the string pointed to by `string` to that **command processor** to be executed...). The grammar in the (current) standard calls statements statements, as does the copy of K&R I have kicking around (2nd edition, 1988). So I stand by my statement (or my command, if you prefer :) ). C is derived from BCPL, but it is not BCPL. And I very much doubt that BCPL compilers issued "command not found" errors, either.

Comment: 'command not found' was the error OP specified error hence I used the same terminology. I only assumed that he MAY be using a C compiler. Irregardless I doubt that its the actual error the OP is getting but rather a short hand.

Comment: @avalon: I'm reasonably sure that OP is quoting the actual errors he gets, although they might be missing the `bash:` at the beginning which would definitely indicate the origin of the error. Try this: `bash -c "using namespace std;`" and see what error message is produced.

Comment: Ah okay, sorry to have caused the confusion.

Comment: @rici  I got "bash: using: command not found"
Before I never got the "bash:" before it.

Comment: oh and this was sudden btw.  I even tested out some code that worked on it before.